# Python: Multiprocessing Queue.put not working for semi-large data

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, put

I am testing out functions of the Queue structure in module multiprocessing. I fail to see why this simple piece of code is unable to terminate for a hardly large data set

Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue

if __name__ == "__main__":

    tobeQueue = Queue()

    for i in range(1,10000):
        tobeQueue.put(i)
```

This code which should be terminating, is working for range less than equal to 3 orders of 10... But not for higher orders of 10 than 3...

Comment: Queues have an init argument maxsize, that when left to zero or None, results in an infinite length Queue.
I just tried adding 100000 elements to a queue on my computer using Python 2.7.5 and it completed successfully.
Put a if i%1000==0: print i` statement in your loop to see if its really the loop's fault. Whatever the problem is, it isn't obvious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah I know now what the problem is.

```
from Queue import Queue
```

and

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

are not the same queue. The multiprocessing (mp) `queue` has some special code in it to allow it to pass values back and forth between processes. It is a consequence of python GIL and threading handicap.

[What is happening, is the queue will not allow the process it is in to die until it is empty.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) Pay special attention to the second red-highlighted **warning**. The loop is finishing normally, the queue is not allowing your python process to terminate because the queue is not in shared memory, like you would expect with threads. I am not entirely familiar with the process behind the mp.Queue, but it involves pickling the items on the queue between the `put` and `get` processes. Thus, eliminating one process abnormally may result in deadlock.

So you need to unload the queue completely, with `queue.get()`, and your process will terminate as expected.

This code will terminate as you would expect:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue

if __name__ == "__main__":

    tobeQueue = Queue()

    for i in range(1,10000):
        tobeQueue.put(i)

    for i in range(1,10000):
        tobeQueue.get() #remove all 9999 items, allow it to die.
```

Comment: Thank you for a lot of clarification on this. But there is still a query.

How does the program then terminate normally for numbers like 10 or 100, ie,
    `for x in range(1,10)` etc.

The code works for small values of the range function.... ie, small data set

Comment: Hmm... that is interesting behavior isn't it? I suspect it has something to do with a Queue not knowing its exact size (it has no __len__ attrib), but I am not certain. The answer may lie in the source, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, really unpredictable behaviour... I hope some others also contribute to this. The data might get garbage collected. Collected huge data takes a lot of time i guess.

Comment: No its not garbage collection. It's definitely the queue locking up the python process. I think whats happening is the Queue, once it hits a certain threshold, starts a `thread` to push the data to the receiving process, using a pipe. All threads run on the same python instance that spawned the thread. Since nobody ever collects it, we deadlock until it is emptied, or `kill -9` it.